# Android M OS, not able to play large video using Nanohttpd streaming

Tags: android, video, nanohttpd

My Code is getting successfully executed below M devices. But on M onward devices it always shows Video cant be played.

I debugged the code and found that RANGE is not getting properly set. So when execution comes to serve method it gets null range. So it tries to play complete file and failed may be due to time out as file size is large.

So can you please let me know who sets this range parameter? How can I control it?

Or how to play video using nanohttp on M onward devices

thanks

Comment: You may want to consider a different embeddable HTTP server, such as the one in AndroidAsync. AFAIK, koush is using that for serving media, so it ay handle your use case better.

Comment: ok. I will evaluate this. But is there any way to correct code so that things wordks with nanohttp.